# Xcode 9.2 certificate used to sign is either expired or revoke

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode9

I used to run an app on my device with no problem using automatic signing of Xcode. Now suddenly it's giving me this error when running the app:
 the certificate used to sign "app name" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.

I am using Xcode 9.2 . I have already tried deleting all of "My Certificates" from keychain , deleting all provisioning profiles. cleaning project but none of them helped.

I have seen so many people have this problem solved by Going To Preferences->Accounts->Team -> View Details and Reset the profile. But there is no View Details in my case (Xcode 9.2)

Any ideas what may help?

Comment: Create a new Certificate: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out. The error message was not helping at all.

This was a project actually exported from Unity3D. In Unity3D I have some post build scripts that modifies Xcode project. It was adding a framework as embedded framework in post build script. I just removed the framework from embedded frameworks and add it again (in the general tab) and it fixed the problem.